# Is it possible to configure Apache Ignite QueryCursor to be autocloseable in the xml configuration file?

Tags: go, cursor, odbc, ignite

I am writing a program in Golang that connects to local Ignite clusters through an ODBC driver package written in Go.

During development I began getting this error repeatedly:

> Too many open cursors (either close other open cursors or increase the
>   limit through
>   ClientConnectorConfiguration.maxOpenCursorsPerConnection)
>   [maximum=128, current=128]

After opening an issue with the golang odbc packgage I was using and providing a sample app, the author was kind enough to help me verify there was no issue in the golang code that would result in leaving cursors opened: https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/issues

I have since attempted to configure the setting for QueryCursor to value `autoclose` in the xml file I use for Ignite Configuration on initiating a cluster. I have used this doc as reference: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/index.html

However after some attempts I am not sure whether my syntax is wrong, or this is simply not a configurable property through the xml configuration file, and that the only way to tell Ignite to close the cursor is in the code, after queries.

Comment: What is Ignite version you are on?

Comment: @isapego was on 2.5.0 and as of today I installed 2.6.0 but still getting the same issue

Comment: just noticed that you have answered me in the Ignite Mailing list as well, thank you so much for your time